# Can not send message to specific user By ConnectionId in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

i can not send message to specific user by connectionId when I try to send all users like this: context.Clients.All.updateMessages(message) - this code is working.
hare is Hub code:

```
public void Send(string userToId, string userForId, string message)
        {
            //Get Recipent (userIdfor) connectionId
            var signalrhelper = new HomeController();
            string userForconnectionId = signalrhelper.GetConnecionIdByUserId(userForId);

            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHubs>();

            string messageSenderConnId= signalrhelper.GetConnecionIdByUserId(userToId);

            //Call Receiver
            context.Clients.Client(userForconnectionId).updateMessages(message);
            //Call Sender
            context.Clients.Client(messageSenderConnId).updateMessages(message);
        }
```

Hare is My View:

```
$(function() {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var notifications = $.connection.chatHubs;

        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        notifications.client.updateMessages = function(data) {

            if (window.location.href.indexOf("Messages/DetailMessage?userId") > -1) {
                $('#timeline-messages').append('{0}'.Stringformat(data));
            } else {
                ReplaceUpdateTargetIdToReturnData("Messages/GetMessages", "#header_inbox_bar", "#systemMessage");
            }

        };
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {

            var myClientId = $.connection.hub.id;
            GetConnectionIdToSignalR("Home", "SaveConnectionIdbyUserName", "userId", @Session["UserId"], "hubConnectionId", myClientId);


            $('#sendMessageButton').click(function() {
                if ($('#sendMessageFiled').val().length > 1) {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    notifications.server.send(@Session["UserId"], myClientId, $('#sendMessageButton').attr("title"), $('#sendMessageFiled').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#sendMessageFiled').val('').focus();
                } else {
                    $('#sendMessageFiled').focus();
                }
            });
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });
```

Can anybody Know what's happen ?

Answer (score 0):

By user, I assume you mean an authenticated user? If that is the case, you have to map connections to users first. For instance, a user can have 2 or more signalr connections. So the first step is mapping users to connections, then you can send a message to the user and all his/her connected agents will receive it.

There are several ways to map connections to users, the guide is here: http://www.google.co.uk/url?q=http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections&sa=U&ei=Tjj-VJuPMsPBOZGGgYgH&ved=0CAsQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNFXoGJOm3mzenAJbz46TUq-Lx2bvA

Comment: Thanks, I have already fixed this problem. My problem was spaces end of connectionIds in db. I trimed and everything working well.

Answer (score 0):

Although this post is already old: I had a similar issue yesterday and it took me hours! I had the connectionIds but no client received a notification. `Context.Clients.All.aMethod(...)` worked fine, but `Context.Clients.Client(theid).aMethod(...)` did not work. I finally realized that I stored the connection-ids in the database as an uniqueIdentifier and MS SQL converted the uniqueIdentifier values to uppercase and therefore the connectionids were not valid any more. I converted the connectinIds to lowercase before publishing to my connected clients and then it worked...maybe you experience a similar problem. But your post with an invalid connectionid because of blanks helped my finding the problem.